# no me funciona el scraping

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup

No se porque no me funcionan el scraping de esta pagina, use el método del xpath donde al inspeccionar la pagina me salen los datos que necesito en forma correcta pero al ejecutarlo en python no se ejecuta correctamente. agradezco su ayuda, muchas gracias

```
           
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import requests
        import pandas as pd
 
        url=requests.get('http://www.ganarchance.com/resultado/astro-luna')
        soup  = BeautifulSoup(url.content,"html.parser")

        resultado = soup.find ('//body/div[3]//div/table[1]/tbody//td[3]')


        print(resultado)
```

Comment: REQUIERO OPTENER EN UN JSON FECHA,NUMEROS DEL SORTEO Y SIGNO

Answer (score 0):

Realmente lo que no te funciona es el selector XPath pero, dado que hay varias tablas de las que querrás recuperar datos puedes simplificar mucho el selector si utilizas CSS.

`.tabla-resultado tr` te va a devolver todas las filas de todas las tablas con la clase `tabla-resultado`, por lo que simplemente tienes que iterar por ellas y comprobar si no es de encabezado y si no tiene ningún colspan (dado que hay filas con un botón)

Con esto podrías hacer algo así:

```
resultado = []
for row in soup.select('.tabla-resultado tr'):
    if len(row.findAll('td')) == 3:
        resultado.append([_.text for _ in row.findAll('td')])
```

Comment: gracias, lo intentare